# Trigger to automatically calculating area when adding polygon in Postgis

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I need help with writing a trigger to automatically update and insert into a column the area of a polygon being created using PostgreSQL/PostGIS and QGIS.

This is what I have but its not updating when I add new features.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calc_area()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
NEW.area_ha := ROUND((st_area(NEW.geom::geography)/10000)::numeric,2);
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER area_calculate AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON public."Guyana_Coastal_Zone"
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE calc_area();
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user please take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Trigger maintenance is more of a DBA SE specialty; you may have better luck there.

Answer (score 4):

change the trigger to `BEFORE INSERT`.
Then the value will be calculated before the values are inserted into the new row.